# Google Photos APIs - Move EXISTING image to album

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

Since few days I've been searching for a solution for a problem described in title.

The problem:
I have some images in google photos and I want to move them to a specific album using Google Photo Api.
I based on https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media.

All what I found was about upload images. Not moves existing ones

Only solution which I see for now is download an image and upload again in specific album what looks no sense.

Answer (score 5):

This is currently not possible.  I've filed a feature request - please vote for it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109505022

Comment: are you serious?  what is Google smoking?